# Problem with a button logic to work on another class in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, telnet

In my program I have 2 classes at this moment it will grow eventually with more classes, the first class is the main class of my windows form where I have all my buttons and text etc. now in my main form I have a button called close connection where when this is click the a loop will end from the second class. the problem I am having is how to accomplished that be able to close that loop from the button of my main class.

Here is the main class code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BarcodeReceivingApp
{



    //TelnetConnection stopConnection = new TelnetConnection();
    public partial class BarcodeReceivingForm : Form
    {
        //GLOBAL VARIABLES
        private const string Hostname = "myip";
        private const int Port = 23;


        public BarcodeReceivingForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void btn_ConnectT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var readData = new TelnetConnection(Hostname, Port);
            readData.ServerSocket(Hostname, Port, this);
        }

        private void btn_StopConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var connection = new TelnetConnection(Hostname, Port);
            connection.CloseConnection();
        }

        private void btn_RemoveItemFromListAt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (var i = lst_BarcodeScan.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                lst_BarcodeScan.Items.RemoveAt(lst_BarcodeScan.SelectedIndices[i]);
            }
        }

        private void BarcodeReceivingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lst_BarcodeScan.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
        }

        private void btn_ApplicationSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bcSettingsForm = new BarcodeReceivingSettingsForm();
            bcSettingsForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Second class code where most of the logic is
In the ReadWrite() method there is where I need to put for example if button.click from the stopconnection then break the loop and close the port 23 connection that part I have it done in my close connection method I am calling after the while loop. write now I have is command variable = exit then break the loop but I don't want to be that why I want the button to do that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BarcodeReceivingApp
{
    public class TelnetConnection
    {
        private Thread _readWriteThread;
        private TcpClient _client;
        private NetworkStream _networkStream;
        private string _hostname;
        private int _port;
        private BarcodeReceivingForm _form;

        public TelnetConnection(string hostname, int port)
        {
            this._hostname = hostname;
            this._port = port;
        }

        public TelnetConnection()
        {

        }

        public void ServerSocket(string ip, int port, BarcodeReceivingForm f)
        {
            this._form = f;
            try
            {
                _client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Failed to connect to server");
                return;
            }

            _networkStream = _client.GetStream();
            _readWriteThread = new Thread(ReadWrite);
            //_readWriteThread = new Thread(() => ReadWrite(f));
            _readWriteThread.Start();
        }


        public void ReadWrite()
        {           
            while (true)
            {
                var command = "";
                if (command == "Exit")
                    break;

                var received = Read();

                if (_form.lst_BarcodeScan.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    _form.lst_BarcodeScan.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { _form.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received + Environment.NewLine); }));
                }
            }

            CloseConnection();
        }

        public string BarcodeRead()
        {
            var reading = Read();

            return reading;
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            var data = new byte[1024];
            var received = "";

            var size = _networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, size);

            return received;
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Closed Connection");
            _networkStream.Close();
            _client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have been searching on google and also on stack overflow something similar to question and I could not find anything that will help my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your loop to stop automatically when the boolean condition changes. Here a small change you can do. You will need to create a new method to call the closing plus changing a bit the `ReadWrite` method

```
private bool isExiting = false;
public void Exit()
{
    isExiting = true;
}

 public void ReadWrite()
 {           
     do
     {     
         var received = Read();

         if (_form.lst_BarcodeScan.InvokeRequired)
         {
             _form.lst_BarcodeScan.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { _form.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received + Environment.NewLine); }));
         }
     } while (!isExiting)

     CloseConnection();
 }
```

Now calling `connection.Exit();` will close everything But you still have an issue. You did not keep the instance of the class in the form for the connection. In the form you need to change the connect and close to use the same object. here are the small changes to both method

```
    private TelnetConnection connection;
    private void btn_ConnectT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new TelnetConnection(Hostname, Port);
        connection.ServerSocket(Hostname, Port, this);
    }

    private void btn_StopConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Exit();
    }
```

Now they both use the same object so it should work properly.

Comment: I made the changes but still not closing the loop is not calling the CloseConnection() method where it will show me the closed connection message after I click the stop connection button that button should close the port telnet 23 and the networkstream.

Comment: @NewCoder Yes i made a mistake in the stop connection. i have corrected it

Comment: That worked great, but only one little problem after I click stop connection button I don't get the closed connection message at that moment but when my program tries to read the receivied data from the loop again I get the closed connection message but still let the last received data to show and then I get the closed the connection. do you know why?

Comment: @NewCoder yes that is due to your order and using a thread. You cannot ensure that when you call for a break that it will break right away.If you change for a `do...while` loop instead it will reduce the amount of time it tries one more time. If you click and it's already reading it wont stop in the middle. It's a separate execution.

Comment: you mean to do a `do...while` loop in the readWrite method loop? or in the ServerSocket method where I am using the thread?

Comment: @NewCoder i have updated with the `do...while` instead but again this will not completely solve the issue. It will reduce the chance to happen by a lot but still it all about random timings.

Comment: I see, I have updated the code. Is there a way to fix that timings? so far your solution works for me but still would like to fix that issue that after I click the stop connection button to stop it completed, any thoughts?

Comment: @NewCoder there is only 2 possible solution. Abort the thread itself, this very dangerous. Second is to not use a thread and find another way to make your software. Imagine that you are a thread and what you do is walking. Each iteration you lift your leg, move your foot forward and then lay down your foot. This is your thread. And me i decide to stop you while the foot is in the air. That is abording the thread while it's doing something. Very not safe. You will be losing information or sending half baked data to the server. That is the reality of multithreading.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but so if I need to get it of the thread what should I used then to read my readwrite method?

Comment: @NewCoder No idea, i would personally stick to the thread. I don't see a problem with that. Every multi threaded software in the world live with it as it's totally normal. As of right now if my answer does answer the original question mark as answer. You might want to develop further your application and post in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to see what can be improved.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for all the help yes your solution did the job, just to keep working on my app if I have further issue I might put another post.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkStream.Read() returns 0 when the socket is closed so you can use that to break out of the loop. So return a null when the read returns 0.

```
public string Read()
{
    var data = new byte[1024];
    var received = "";

    var size = _networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    if(size == 0)
        return null;

    received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, size);

    return received;
}
```

and in your ReadWrite method

```
public void ReadWrite()
{           
    while (true)
    {
        var command = "";
        if (command == "Exit")
            break;

        var received = Read();
        if(received == null)
            break;

        if (_form.lst_BarcodeScan.InvokeRequired)
        {
        _form.lst_BarcodeScan.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { _form.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received + Environment.NewLine); }));
        }
    }

    CloseConnection();
}
```

Comment: I added to my code for still not breaking the loop when I click my stop connection button, still keep reading data from the port 23

Comment: @NewCoder It is because you are creating a new connection on your close connection button. You should make your connection variable global in your class and modify your connect and disconnect methods so that they will access global variable.